# When should you use plus, minus, times functions instead of using the operators in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I cannot think of a case where using the Kotlin built-in plus, minus, times etc. functions would return a different result from just using the corresponding operators (+, -, *). Why would you ever want to use these functions in your Kotlin code?

Comment: They're exactly the same, at all times. They get converted to the exact same bytecode. We just need need the named operators for operator overloading.

Comment: The only little difference is that if you overload one of these operator and make it `infix`, the symbol form will have normal precedence but the named infix form won't have any. E.g.: `(foo + bar * baz) != (foo plus bar times baz)`

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#operator-overloading

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just in case you aren't aware, these are [operator overloads](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#operator-overloading). The named functions are how the operators' functionality is defined.

There is a case for using the named versions. The function calls don't pay attention to operator precedence and are evaluated sequentially if you chain them.

```
val x = 1
val y = 2
val z = 3

println(x + y * z)          // equivalent to 1 + (2 * 3) -> 7
println(x.plus(y).times(z)) // equivalent to (1 + 2) * 3 -> 9
```

This could be clearer than using the operators if you have a lot of nested parentheses, depending on the context of the type of math you're doing.

```
result = ((x - 7) * y - z) * 10

// vs

result = x.minus(7).times(y).minus(z).times(10)
```

It's not really applicable for basic algebra like this, but you might have classes with operator overloads where the logic can be more easily reasoned through with the sequential approach.

Answer (score 6):

By explicitly stating function names you can perform a [safe call](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) on a nullable number  which cannot be done with an operator.

For example:

```
fun doubleOrZero(num: Int?) : Int {
    return num?.times(2) ?: 0
}
```